# Use Spanish Localization as Catalan Localization

Tags: ios, localization

I'm dealing with localization

The main langauge for my app is english, but it has been localized to spanish as well. When a user uses Catalan langauge, my app needs to fall back to spanish instead english. Is this possible without supplying the catalan localization?

**Edit**

I found this [apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html) saying:

> You can choose from more than 100 different languages and dialects
>   designated by regions to localize your app. However, the more general
>   you make your localized resources, **the more regions you can support
>   with a single set of resources**. This can save a lot of space in your
>   app bundle and help reduce localization costs.

Comment: I guess You have to localize to all language you want to use in app. 
Refer this lib that i have created https://github.com/dipkasyap/DGLocalization If you need any help regarding   library then msg mg !

Answer (score 0):

iPhone users can choose their language preferences.
As a catalan, i have my iPhone in Catalan, and second in spanish. So when an app is only translated to spanish, NSLocalizedString search for catalan first, if the app doesn't support catalan, it search for spanish and last for english.
So it's not your job to translate for all possible languages! ;)
It's iphone users job to put the correct language preferences